# Python преобразование двоичного кода в символы

Tags: python

Как двоичный код в питоне перевести в символы,хотяб в кракозябру(двоичный код был изменён)

```
10010111100110101001001110010011100100001101111110011010100010011001101010001101100001101001000010010001100110101101111111011110
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int('0b110100001100101011011000110110001101111', 2)
s = n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode()
```

Comment: Попробуйте с моими значениями :

Comment: s = n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @positiv очевидно, ваше значение кодировано в двоичную форму не из utf-8. Чтобы декодировать, нужно знать исходную кодировку и передать её в метод `decode`.

Comment: Она кодировалась в utf-8 потом я на место каждого ноля ставил единицу,на место каждой еденицы ставил 0, ну теперь я не знаю что это за кодировкам

Comment: Теперь это шум, который декодировать невозможно без обратного преобразования.